# Is this necessary conditions, sufficient for the convergence of an infinite product?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

For the infinite product $\prod_{k=1}^\infty z_k$ to converge, it is necessary that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ a $N$ exists such that for every $k > N$ and for every integer $r \geq 1$:
 $$|z_{k+1}z_{k+2}\cdots z_{k+r} - 1| < \varepsilon$$

Is it a sufficient condition? if the answer is "NO", How can I change the condition to become sufficient?

Comment: It's the Cauchy criterion. Necessary and sufficient. (Under the assumption that $a_m = z_m$, otherwise the behaviour of the $a_m$ is probably unrelated to the convergence of $\prod z_k$.) If you restrict to $\varepsilon \leqslant 1/2$ [any constant $< 1$ would do] and take logarithms, it's plain that this is equivalent to the convergence of $\sum \log z_k$ [where the sum starts at a point such that $z_k \neq 0$ for all considered $k$].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an infinite product to converge, you first take it's ln (or log of any base, but ln is standard) with by the identities of log will turn the product in a infinite sum, if this sum converges, so does de product.

PS: I am not being tecnical here, I would need to prove this fact if so, but I believe that the intuition is more important.